# liferay 6.2 jboss bundle not working

Tags: jboss7.x, liferay-6

I downloaded life ray 6.2 jboss bundle from liferay home, and install it, but when starting jboss, it always failed at deploying anything and complains about

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/data/osgi/portal/org.apache.felix.scr.jar (No such file or directory)

Comment: Have you followed the steps from this link ? http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-15-en from error seems to have missing jar, try to validate steps.

Comment: Well, this is an own installation, I did install jboss manually and deploy life ray, it works, but I though the bundle should take care everything and you just need to unzip it. that is the meaning of the bundle I guess.

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo`

```
sudo ./standalone.sh
```

make sure your user is a SU

Comment: you can change the owner of the folders